# (Flutter) How to get other users' info from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

## 1. The Context of the Problem

In my app, I'm creating a screen where the user could see other people's ranks. For that, inevitably, I'm going to need other users' names, profile pictures, etc. So, is there a way of querying that info through `Firebase`'s authentication API? Or, for example, would I have to save that kind of data in a separate collection when the user logs in for the first time — doesn't sound like a good security practice to me.

## 2. How I think it would look like

I imagine the workflow would look a bit like this:

```dart
// ...
for (String userEmail in listOfUserEmailsInRanking){
  UserInfo userData = FirebaseAuth.instance.getUserData(
    email: userEmail
  );
  userDisplayName = userData.displayName;
  userPhoto = userData.photoUrl;
  // ...
}
```

My idea is that there should be some API following the example of `displayName` and `photoUrl`, which are both properties available from the `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` method.

Comment: I recommend watching this playlist to understand how Firebase's authentication and Cloud Firestore work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfA3NWDBPZ4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to use the Firebase Authentication client API to allow a user to query for other users.  If you want to expose user account data to other users, you should write some code to write the required user data to a database, and query the database instead.

If you have concerns about security, and you're using a Firebase data (Realtime Database or Firestore) then look into using security rules to determine who can read and write its data.

Comment: Is it possible to point me to some official documentation that has this registered?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users - but there is no direct answer to your question since this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your second option can be implemented without compromising security. If you really intend to share some user data (which I suppose is not sensitive) you can create a shared separate collection of just that data and link it to the owner through some ID which you also keep in a private collection of that owner's properties.